# Where is the tab/indent options in Notepad++ 5.5?

Tags: notepad++

I recently upgraded to Notepad++ 5.5, and I can't find the tab indentation options.  Does anybody know where they were moved?  They used to be easily locatable in the Preferences menu, but apparently this has changed...

Comment: If you don't want to modify a language, but just change the current default, try: Settings, Preferences, Tab Settings, Tab Size.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> Settings -> Preferences.
>
> Go to the Language Menu/Tab Settings tab.  The tab options are on the right-hand side.

Tab/indent away, good sir!

Comment: Okay, I'm blind; they moved the "tab" settings to the tab tab. lol

Comment: To be fair, NP++ config is hideous.

Comment: sheesh. You'd think that would be a text box or an incrementer.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, I wonder how they organize it. I can better organize it using a random diceroll.

Comment: In 7.7.1 find it under "Settings -> Preferences... -> Language -> Tab Settings". Set by clicking the underlined number. Check the list of languages for overrides of the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean tab size?  If so, check under Edit Components.

Comment: 'Edit Components'?? What do you mean?